# Auto updating JavaScript dependancy in functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I'm enqueuing scripts with dependency in `functions.php` file like:

```
wp_enqueue_script('ads', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ads.js', array( ), '1.6', true);
wp_enqueue_script('banners', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/banners.js', array( 'ads-REKLAMY' ), $timestamp = filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/js/banners.js' ), true);
```

`banners.js` is a script which uses imported arrays from `ads.js`. I need to update `ads.js` file automatically whenever I make changes there.

For now I use version parameter like `"1.6"`. So I need to manually change it to, for example, `"1.7"` and change import line in `banners.js` file.

Of course `banners.js` updates automatically with timestamp. Is there a way to do that with dependancy file as well?

And do I do that with import in file using dependency? Basically I need `ads.js`, the dependency file with exported arrays, to update automatically whenever I make changes there. Any solution will do except Webpack.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. For example, why did you use dependency as `array( 'ads-REKLAMY' )`, why is it not `array( 'ads' )`? Is there another file with handle `ads-REKLAMY`?

Comment: I've edited the question to the best of my understanding, and answered the question accordingly. I think you are trying to change the dependency handle name, like `ads-REKLAMY` to get the change from `ads.js`. That is not necessary. Please check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yea it should be `array( 'ads' )` i was just changing names a bit and forgot to change that one too and yea you understood my problem correctly but what about import in banners.js file should it be just `import { selectADS, sidebarADS, mobileADS } from "./ads.js";` ?

Comment: Scripts added with `wp_enqueue_script` cannot be used as a ES6 module by default. WordPress doesn't support that. I recommend you add `selectADS, sidebarADS, mobileADS` as global JavaScript variables in `ads.js`, and then access them from `banners.js` normally. If you must use them as modules (with `import` statement), then there is workaround for that, like [this link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56313#comment:1) explains.

Comment: Ive been using them as modules exactly like that solution explains but now there are problems with import, so can I do it without importing them? `selectADS, sidebarADS, mobileADS` are functions not variables and when I try to use them in another file without import it doesnt work even tho file with them  `ads.js` is loaded first.

Comment: Please ask another question with those function code. In WPSE it's recommended to ask one question at a time. Too many questions (even related) in the same post makes it difficult for others to find. In short I can say if they are functions, you should be able to call them without import (depending on how you've coded them). I cannot comment further without looking at the code first.

Comment: Ok I did ask another question, tried to explain it as best as I can, really hope its understanable. [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/413841/loading-newest-dependency-file-in-functions-php)

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, you have two JavaScript files: `ads.js` and `banner.js`.

You want the site to load the updated version of both of these files, whenever any of these files are changed.

If this understanding is correct, then you may do the following:

```php
function my_custom_theme_scripts() {
    $ads_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/ads.js' );
    $banners_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/banners.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ads',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ads.js',
        array(),
        $ads_version,
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'banners',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/banners.js',
        array( 'ads' ),
        $banners_version,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_theme_scripts' );
```

This way, whenever any of the files are changed, only the updated versions will be loaded in the frontend. When `ads.js` is changed, but `banners.js` is unchanged, the same old `banners.js` will still get the new `ads.js`, because the new `ads.js` will be loaded by the `$ads_version` timestamp. There's no need to change the dependency handle.

> **Note:** I've used `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory` for consistency (for the currently active theme).
>
> Mixing up `get_template_directory_uri()` and `plugin_dir_path()` will work in theory, but that sort of inconsistency may break your code in future. `plugin_dir_path()` is supposed to be used with plugins, and `get_template_directory_uri()` for the parent theme.
>
> ---
>
> Also, I've added:
>
> `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_theme_scripts' );`
>
> Just in case you are missing the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. The code will not work properly without it.
>
> Of course, if you are already using the action hook properly, like:
>
> `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '<function-that-enqueues-scripts>' );`
>
> then please don't add it again.