# Loading newest dependency javascript module file in functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

Continuing from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/413796/110572):

I have scripts enqueued in `functions.php` file so scripts load only on certain pages (I cut most of them in code below):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'plugin_is_page' );
function plugin_is_page() {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('ads-search', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ads-search.js', array( 'ads' ), $timestamp = filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/js/ads-search.js' ), true);
    }
}
```

Now, each of them uses dependency `ads.js` file witch contains array of objects (ads) and functions to display them. In files like `ads-search.js`, I only call said functions on search results page.

I need to load latest version of each file every time (every time it changes). For now it is enqueued like this, with `banners.js` file it loads on every single page.

```
function my_custom_theme_scripts() {
    $ads_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/ads.js' );
    $banners_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/ads-banners.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ads',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ads.js',
        array(),
        $ads_version,
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ads-banners',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ads-banners.js',
        array( 'ads' ),
        $banners_version,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_theme_scripts' );
```

So how do I use functions coded in dependency `ads.js` file across all my scripts like `ads-banners.js` or `ads-search.js`?

Importing them wont work even if I load scripts as modules, because then I would need to include version in `import` line and doing just `import { selectADS, sidebarADS, mobileADS } from "./ads.js";` won't work.

All functions are coded in the same way, example one:

```
export async function selectADS(adNumber, element, adsArray) {
  let usedNum = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (1) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * adsArray.length);

    if (!usedNum.includes(randomNum)) {
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", adsArray[randomNum].link);
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

      let ad = document.createElement("img");
      ad.setAttribute("alt", adsArray[randomNum].alt);
      ad.setAttribute("src", adsArray[randomNum].src);

      element.appendChild(link);
      link.appendChild(ad);

      usedNum.push(randomNum);
      i++;
      if (i == adNumber) break;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to call `selectADS` in another file it throws `function is not defined error`.

So, how can I enqueue modules in WordPress, so that live changes to `ads.js` file in loaded properly without error?

Comment: Attach the functions to the window object and call them the same way eg. `window.selectADS = () => {}` and `window.selectADS()`

Comment: "*I would need to include version in import line*" - see [dynamic module loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#dynamic_module_loading), which allows something like `import( './ads.js?ver=' + ADS_SCRIPT_VERSION ).then( module => module.selectADS( ... ) )`. Or just turn your ads module into a "normal script", i.e. without the `export` statement... But what you're asking is a JS question, so I voted to close it.

Comment: @SallyCJ part of this question is WP related, since WP doesn't directly support `type="module"` yet. So IMHO, this question shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

Import statement like:

```js
import { export1 } from "./module-name.js";
```

is called **static `import` declaration**.

Dynamic query string (to force load the latest file) cannot be used in static `import` declarations. So, to solve this problem, you'll have to choose one of the following four options:

1. Remove `export` and `import` statements from all the JavaScript files and enqueue them as non-module JavaScript.
2. Don't enqueue `ads.js` in WordPress, only pass version number of `ads.js` file as a JavaScript global variable with `wp_add_inline_script()` function to the page, and dynamically import `ads.js` as a module from `banners.js` and `ads-search.js`.
3. Enqueue `ads.js` as a module, pass version number of `ads.js` file as a JavaScript global variable with `wp_add_inline_script()` function to the page, enqueue `banners.js` and `ads-search.js` as non-module JavaScript (with `ads.js` in the dependency array), and dynamically import `ads.js` as a module from `banners.js` and `ads-search.js`. This is slightly different from option-2 and may have some benefits depending on implementation.
4. Use a bundler like Rollup or Webpack and build a single minified script using a file watcher and enqueue the build minified JavaScript file in WordPress as a non-module JavaScript file. I'd recommend this method, but would not explain it here as it out of the scope of this question.

### Option-1: Make all JS files non-module

Just remove `export` and `import` statements from all the JavaScript files, like below:

```js
// in ads.js
// removed the export declaration
async function selectADS(adNumber, element, adsArray) {
  let usedNum = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (1) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * adsArray.length);

    if (!usedNum.includes(randomNum)) {
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", adsArray[randomNum].link);
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

      let ad = document.createElement("img");
      ad.setAttribute("alt", adsArray[randomNum].alt);
      ad.setAttribute("src", adsArray[randomNum].src);

      element.appendChild(link);
      link.appendChild(ad);

      usedNum.push(randomNum);
      i++;
      if (i == adNumber) break;
    }
  }
}

// in banners.js
// call selectADS function normally, no import declaration
selectADS();
```

Then in the WordPress end, enqueue them in `my_custom_theme_scripts()` as you've written in the question.

### Option-2: pass `ads.js` version to JS & dynamically import `ads.js`

If for some reason you have to keep the `export` declaration in `ads.js`, and still want to import the latest file in `banners.js` and `ads-search.js`, you'll need to make some changes in WordPress enqueue code and in the JavaScript code of `banners.js` and `ads-search.js`.

For example, your `my_custom_theme_scripts()` function can be like this:

```php
function my_custom_theme_scripts() {
    $ads_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/ads.js' );
    $banners_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/banners.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'banners',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/banners.js',
        array(),
        $banners_version,
        true
    );
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'banners',
        'const My_Custom_Ads_Version = "' . $ads_version . '";',
        'before'
    );
}
```

In this case, `ads.js` file can be like before with `export` declaration, and `banners.js` file can dynamically `import` it like below:

```js
(async () => {  
    if( typeof My_Custom_Ads_Version !== 'undefined' ) {
        const adsModule = await import( `./ads.js?ver=${My_Custom_Ads_Version}` );
        const selectADS = adsModule.selectADS;
        selectADS();
    }
})();
```

You'll have to make similar changes to `ads-search.js`. After that your code will work.

Remember, in this case `export` declarations can be like before (in `ads.js`), but the import statements in `banners.js` and `ads-search.js` should be changed from static `import` declaration to dynamic `import` statements as shown in the code above.

### Option-3: Enqueue `ads.js` as a module, pass `ads.js` version to JS & dynamically import `ads.js`

This option is very similar to **option-2** above. However, option-2 imports `ads.js` in runtime. So if an implementation wants to delay the execution of `ads.js` module objects, but still wants to load the `ads.js` module with page load, then this implementation will be preferable.

To do this, you'll have to first hook into `script_loader_tag` filter, so that WordPress adds `type="module"` in `<script>` tag.

Following is an example WordPress code that implements it:

```php
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_custom_module_support', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
function my_custom_module_support( $tag, $handle ) {
    if( strpos( $handle, 'my_custom_module_' ) === 0 ) {
        if( current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'script' ) ) { 
            return substr_replace( $tag, '<script type="module"', strpos( $tag, '<script' ), 7 );
        }
        else {
            return substr_replace( $tag, 'module', strpos( $tag, 'text/javascript' ), 15 );
        }
    }

    return $tag;
}
function my_custom_theme_scripts() {
    $ads_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/ads.js' );
    $banners_version = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/banners.js' );

    // we are loading ads.js as a module.
    // my_custom_module_support() function checks any handle
    // that begins with "my_custom_module_" and adds type="modle"
    // to print it as a ES6 module script 
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_custom_module_ads',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ads.js',
        array(),
        $ads_version,
        true
    );
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'my_custom_module_ads',
        'const My_Custom_Ads_Version = "' . $ads_version . '";'
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'banners',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/banners.js',
        array( 'my_custom_module_ads' ),
        $banners_version,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_theme_scripts' );
```

With this option as well, `ads.js` file can be like before with `export` declaration, and `banners.js` and `ads-search.js` can dynamically `import` from `ads.js` as shown in option-2 above.

However, with this option, the browser will load `ads.js` module file before it is imported dynamically in `banners.js`. So when the dynamic import is performed, the browser will just use the already loaded file.

In most cases this is not significant. However, it can be significant when you perform the dynamic import on an event like below code (especially if `ads.js` file takes significant time to load):

```js
// sample ads.js code
console.log( 'ads.js loaded:START' );
export async function selectADS( adNumber, element, adsArray ) {
    console.log( 'ads.js as a module loaded' );
};
console.log( 'ads.js loaded:END' );

// banners.js code
console.log( 'banners.js load:START' );

let clicked = false;
document.addEventListener( 'click', async (event) => {   
    if( ! clicked && typeof My_Custom_Ads_Version !== 'undefined' ) {
        const adsModule = await import( `./ads.js?ver=${My_Custom_Ads_Version}` );
        const selectADS = adsModule.selectADS;
        selectADS();
    }
    clicked = true;
});

console.log( 'banners.js load:END' );
```

With this implementation, if the `ads.js` file is significantly large  and it's only dynamically imported on an event, code becomes simpler without having to wait for the imported file.

However, this is not the most significant advantage, because you can rewrite that JS code to still import early. More significant advantage of this implementation is if you use a caching system or a bundler that watches changes in HTML code. With this option it's easier to handle such scenario as opposed to option-2 (because with option-2 `adj.js` is not visible from HTML).

Comment: "3. Enqueue `ads.js` as a module ... and dynamically import `ads.js` as a module from `banners.js` and `ads-search.js`" - why would it be enqueued, if it's going to be dynamically imported?

Comment: @SallyCJ I've updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Ok, but the author said, "*I need to load latest version of each file everytime*".

Comment: No, not every time, **every time it's changed**. There's a significant difference.

Comment: @SallyCJ actually it's a continuation of this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/413796/110572).

Comment: Yes, "latest version", and I did notice the use of `filemtime()`. It's just I did not have a chance to edit that comment before you replied. Anyway, +1.